# Why is the British version of "tire" is "tyre"?

Tags: tire

I saw someone spell tire wrong, so I edited it and it was rejected, because he was British. Is there a reason why British people use tyre instead of tire?

Comment: Because it's the proper English spelling, maybe! ;-)

Comment: Not really..., dude.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the [English Language & Usage Stackexchange](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I guess those Brits just don't know how to spell.

Comment: Let's do the neighbours a big favour and close this discussion on colours and flavours.<G>

Comment: Because North Americans never learnt to spell "tyre", of course.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason they call diaper nappys? or elevators lifts? It's the queen's English. It differs from us american folk.

> In British English both spellings are correct, but both words mean
> totally different things.
>
> In all of the English speaking world, the word tire when used as a
> verb means to become exhausted/sleepy.
>
> In Britain and many other Commonwealth nations, the word tyre is a
> noun, it's the word we use for the outer rubber part of a vehicle
> wheel.  For example, a bicycle tyre, or a car tyre.  In the USA the
> word tyre is spelt tire.
>
> Here are a couple of examples of British English usage: Since the
> onset of her illness, she tires very easily. I find that I tire quite
> easily these days. The car tyres need to be replaced. The bicycle tyre
> has a puncture.
>
> In American English, all of the sentences above would use the spelling
> "tire".

[Source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-right-spelling-tire-or-tyre)

This may or may not be a question for the English language and Usage stack though.

Comment: Oh, ok. I am from america, so seeing "tyre" in use will sometimes confuse me. But thanks. And I wasn't thinking when I posted this.